# Place logo on top of page next to edge

Tags: floats

Before anything, this question may have been asked already, but I can't find it.
I want to place a picture right on top of the page letting no white space between the top edge of the page and the top edge of the picture. I have already fitted the picture width to the paper width like this:

```
\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{mypicture}}
```

Thanks for all and sorry about my spelling.

Comment: In every page or just in the first one?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to use the `eso-pic` package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,788){\rule{21cm}{2cm}}} 

Hello

\end{document}
```

You might need to play with the settings but basically this is one way to do it. To have the picture on each page just remove the '*'.

[image: result]

Comment: Ehhh, I can't get the same result. I get the picture centered verticaly and without the page width. Can you explain me a little bit more how it works?

Comment: Try by changing `\textwidth` to `\paperwidth`, the following line works nicely here: `\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,820){\makebox[\paperwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=1cm]{tulpen}}}}`

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me. Is there a way to tell latex to stick the picture to the top edge? Or something like this: \vspace*{-xxx}\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{mypicture}}, but I cant know what xxx is.

Comment: Check egreg's solution then. The code works fine for me but I don't know your setup.

Answer (score 3):

With the `picture` package you don't even have to guess:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,\dimexpr\paperheight-1cm){%
  \makebox[\paperwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=1cm]{tulpen}}%
}}

Hello
\newpage
Hello

\end{document}
```

If you use `\AddToShipoutPicture` (without the `*`), the image will be added to every page.

Comment: Note: the -1cm part needs to be adjusted according to your image